# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left\{\frac{1\cdot 3\dots 2n-1 }{2\cdot 4\dots 2n}\cdot\frac{4n+3}{2n+2}\right\}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

*Show if the inf series
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left\{\frac{1\cdot3\dots2n-1 }{2\cdot 4\dots2n}\cdot\frac{4n+3}{2n+2}\right\}^2$
converges.*

My thought:

When $2n=2^k$, $\frac{1\cdot 3\dots2n-1 }{2\cdot 4\dots2n}\cdot \frac{4n+3}{2n+2}
\approx (1-1/4)^1\cdot (1-1/8)^2\dots(1-1/(2^k))^{2^{k-2}}  \approx (1-1/4)^{k-1},$
and so the $n$th item =
$((1-1/4)^{k-1})^2=(9/16)^{k-1}$.

When $2n \neq 2^k$, we have $2^{k-1}<2n<2^k$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1\cdot 3\dots2n-1 }{2\cdot 4\dots2n}\cdot \frac{4n+3}{2n+2}
\approx (1-1/4)^1\cdot (1-1/8)^2\dots(1-1/(2^{k-1}))^{2^{k-3}}\cdot(1-1/(2^k))^{n-(2^{k-2})}\\
\approx (1-1/4)^{k-2}\cdot (1-1/(2^k))^{n-(2^{k-2})},
\end{align*}
where $0<n-2^{k-2}<2^{k-2}$.

Then sum $(2^{k-2}+1)$ th to $n'$ th terms, for $2^{k-1}<2n'<=2^k$,
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n=2^{k-2}+1}^{n’}\left\{\frac{1\cdot3\dots2n-1 }{2. 4\dots2n}\cdot \frac{4n+3}{2n+2}\right\}^2
\approx \sum\limits_{n=2^{k-2}+1}^{n'} (1-1/4)^{2(k-2)}.(1-1/(2^k))^{2(n-(2^{k-2}))}\\
=(1-1/4)^{2(k-2)}\cdot \frac{(1-1/(2^k))^2}{1-(1-1/(2^k))^2}\cdot(1-(1-1/(2^k))^2)^{n’-(2^{k-2})})\\
=(9/16)^{(k-2}\cdot (2^{k-1}-1)\cdot (1-\frac{n'-(2^{k-2})}{2^{k-1}}),$
\end{align*}
which, when $2n'=2^k$, approximates
$(9/16)^{k-2}\cdot (2^{k-1}-1)\cdot(1-1/2)\approx (9/16)^{k-2}\cdot (2^{k-2}).$

(All the terms approximates $(9/16)^{k-1}$, and so the sum is roughly $(9/16)^{k-1}\cdot2^{k-2}$. This gives a little larger estimation.)

Therefore the infinite series equals
$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n=2^{k-2}+1}^{n'} \approx \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} (9/16)^{k-2}\cdot (2^{k-2})=\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} (9/8)^{k-2},$$
which diverges, and so the series possibly diverges.$

Given the final approximation being $\sum a^n$ where a is near 1, a little difference in the approximations above could change the convergence. Were the series convergent and had the approximations made it not, which one causes  that? Besides, are there other methods?

Comment: Use \infty for $\infty$ :)

Comment: Better use LaTeX/MathJax `\cdot` symbol, rendered as $\cdot$, for multiplication, than a 'full stop' punctuation mark. Similary, `\dots`, rendered $\dots$ for implied sequence.

Comment: Try taking sums of logarithms instead

Comment: You can also utilize `\left` and `\right` for brackets to make them adjust to their contents. compare `\{\frac 23\}` → $\{\frac 23\}$ to `\left\{\frac 23\right\}` → $\left\{\frac 23\right\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1\times3\times\ldots\times (2n-1)=\frac{1\times2\times\ldots\times 2n}{2\times 4\times\ldots\times 2n}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$. Thus
$$ \frac{1\times3\times\ldots\times(2n-1)}{2\times4\times\ldots\times 2n}=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2} $$
Now, using Stirling's approximation $n!\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$, we have
$$ \frac{1\times3\times\ldots\times(2n-1)}{2\times4\times\ldots\times 2n}\frac{4n+3}{2n+2}\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim} 2\frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}}{4^n\times 2\pi n\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}}\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\frac{2}{\sqrt{n\pi}} $$
and thus your series diverges. Your approximations does not work since you find a sum of the form $\sum a^n$ which can't lead to $\frac{4\ln n}{\pi}$ (using $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim} \ln n$).

Comment: C'est une sorte d'intégrale de Wallis.

Answer (score 2):

You can show the divergence of this series in a quite elementary way using a little trick by estimating

$$a_n:=\frac 12\cdot \frac 34 \cdot \frac 56 \cdots \frac{2n-1 }{2n}  \geq \frac 12\cdot \frac 23 \cdot \frac 45 \cdots \frac{2n-2}{2n-1} =: c_n $$

So, you have

$$a_n^2 \geq a_nc_n = \frac 1{4n}$$

Hence,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_n\frac{4n+3}{2n+2}\right)^2\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{4n}\left(\frac{4n+3}{2n+2}\right)^2\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{4n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Initial series is equivalent to series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot .. \cdot(2n-1) }{2 \cdot 4 \cdot .. \cdot (2n)}\right)^2$$
So we have
$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \left(1+ \frac{1}{2n+1}  \right)^2 = 1+\frac{1}{n} +\frac{\theta_n}{n^2}$$
Where $\theta_n$ is bounded. So accordingly [Gauss test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Gauss%27s_test) series diverges.